# Merge by group and closest integer value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge, data.table

I have two dataframes that I want to merge, such as the following:

```
df1 <- data.table(
  
  color = c("Green", "Green", "Red","Red"),
  year = c(1995, 2001,2010,1997)
)


df2 <- data.table(
  color = c("Green", "Green", "Red", "Blue"),
  value = 1:4,
  year = c(1996, 2002, 2001, 2003)
)
```

I want to merge these such that the all the observations in df1 are kept, but they are only paired with the observation from df2 with the closest year value, within the color group. **I would ideally like to use `tidyverse` for this.**

I tried this:

```
df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = 'color', suffix = c('.1', '.2')) %>%
  group_by(color) #%>%
  filter(abs(year.1 - year.2) == min(abs(year.1 - year.2)))
```

However, this leaves me with only one observation of each "color", not all the observations in df1. How do I merge so that all observations from df1 are maintained and only merged by the color and the closest year value? Also, is it possible to specify this as nearest year before/after/either?

The result should be the following:

```
  df3 <- data.table(
  
  color = c("Green", "Green", "Red","Red"),
  year = c(1995, 2001,2010,1997),
  value = c(1,2,3,3)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "closest" year, we could do:

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, join_by(color)) %>%
  arrange( year.x, abs(year.x - year.y)) %>%
  slice(1, .by = c(color, year.x))

#  color year.x value year.y
#1 Green   1995     1   1996
#2   Red   1997     3   2001
#3 Green   2001     2   2002
#4   Red   2010     3   2001
```

For "closest before/after", we can do:

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, join_by(color, closest(year >= year)))

#  color year.x value year.y
#1 Green   1995    NA     NA
#2 Green   2001     1   1996
#3   Red   2010     3   2001
#4   Red   1997    NA     NA

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, join_by(color, closest(year <= year)))
    
#  color year.x value year.y
#1 Green   1995     1   1996
#2 Green   2001     2   2002
#3   Red   2010    NA     NA
#4   Red   1997     3   2001
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```r
library(data.table)

df1[, value := df2[df1, value, on = c("color == color", "year == year"), 
                   roll = "nearest"]][]

#>    color year value
#> 1: Green 1995     1
#> 2: Green 2001     2
#> 3:   Red 2010     3
#> 4:   Red 1997     3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>